# Word for the list of compositions of a Classical composer?

Tags: composition, terminology, classical-music

Either I'm being stupid or my brain is not working properly...

Is there a word for the list of compositions of a Classical composer? I can only think of 'discography' for a performer but that's not what I'm looking for, and I can't seem to find anything online.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We typically refer to a composer's *oeuvre*. Since it's borrowed from the French, its usage in English is often italicized.

If you're looking for an English phrase, we can otherwise talk about someone's "compositional output." I've occasionally heard "body of work," but that strikes me as something used more in other arts and less common when dealing with composers.

Comment: In the age of Unicode one may even use that nice oe-ligature as in French: *œuvre*, see [free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/oeuvre).

Answer (score 0):

Before computers were widespread, I heard the word "output" used.  I prefer *oeuvre* instead of just "work" (as Richard mentioned.) English likes (to anthropomorphize) to borrow words from other languages with similar meanings to get Anglicized words with similar but separate meanings. (Done by filing the serial number off of the word and claiming as its own.)

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best single English word is *catalogue*.

Answer (score -1):

Output.  Oeuvre.  Works/Body of work.  I think that's about it.